# Is there a way to sort string lists by numbers inside of the strings?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way to sort something like:

```dart
List<String> hi = ['1hi', '2hi','5hi', '3hi', '4hi'];
```

to this?

```dart
['1hi', '2hi','3hi', '4hi', '5hi']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort the list like this:

```
hi.sort();
```

(because numbers sort before letters in its implementation)

Comment: This probably won't do what you expect if there are numbers greater than or equal to 10.

Answer (score 15):

Just calling `List<String>.sort()` by itself will do a [*lexicographic* sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order).  That is, your strings will be sorted in character code order, and `'10'` will be sorted before `'2'`.  That usually isn't expected.

A lexicographic sort will work *if* your numbers have leading `0`s to ensure that all numbers have the same number of digits.  However, if the number of digits is variable, you will need to *parse* the values of the numbers for sorting.  A more general approach is to provide a callback to `.sort()` to tell it how to determine the relative ordering of two items.

Luckily, [`package:collection`](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) has a [`compareNatural`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/compareNatural.html) function that can do this for you:

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

List<String> hi = ['1hi', '2hi','5hi', '3hi', '4hi'];
hi.sort(compareNatural);
```

If your situation is a bit more complicated and `compareNatural` doesn't do what you want, you can make your own parsing callback, such as via a regular expression:

```dart
/// Returns the integer prefix from a string.
///
/// Returns null if no integer prefix is found.
int parseIntPrefix(String s) {
  var re = RegExp(r'(-?[0-9]+).*');
  var match = re.firstMatch(s);
  if (match == null) {
    return null;
  }
  return int.parse(match.group(1));
}

int compareIntPrefixes(String a, String b) {
  var aValue = parseIntPrefix(a);
  var bValue = parseIntPrefix(b);
  if (aValue != null && bValue != null) {
    return aValue - bValue;
  }

  if (aValue == null && bValue == null) {
    // If neither string has an integer prefix, sort the strings lexically.
    return a.compareTo(b);
  }

  // Sort strings with integer prefixes before strings without.
  if (aValue == null) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
}

void main() {
  List<String> hi = ['1hi', '2hi','5hi', '3hi', '4hi'];
  hi.sort(compareIntPrefixes);
}
```

Comment: `hi.sort(compareNatural);` saved my day!

Comment: @MutluSimsek likewise! Perfect for address like 8a, 8b, 9, 10, 10a, 11, etc

Answer (score 1):

If you have a more complex List

To sort the List "myList" after the key "ID" I do the following:

Example Values for ID: AAA00001, AAA0101, AAA0002 ...

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

myList.sort((a, b) => compareNatural(a['ID'], b['ID']));
```