# How do I sort a string list using regular expressions in dart?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, comparable

I'm essentially looking for another way to sort a string list besides the .sort()
Using that for my purpose gives me `type '_SecItem' is not a subtype of type 'Comparable<dynamic>'`
I'm trying to sort a string list by the numerical numbers in front of the strings. Something like:

```dart
List<String> hi = ['05stack', '03overflow', '01cool','04is', '02uToo'];
```

to this:

```dart
['01cool', '02uToo', '03overflow', '04is', '05stack']
```

Comment: [Didn't you just ask this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61434038/is-there-a-way-to-sort-string-lists-by-numbers-inside-of-the-strings/) Did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61435170/179715) not help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a function to extract the number like

```
int extractNumber(String srt){
  RegExp regex = new RegExp(r"(\d+)");
  return regex.allMatches(srt).toList().map((m){
    return srt.substring(m.start, m.end);
  }).toList().map((v)=>int.parse(v)).first;
}

void main(){
  List<String> test = ['05stack', '03overflow', '01cool','04is', '02uToo'];
  test.sort((a, b)=>extractNumber(a)>extractNumber(b) ? 1 : -1);
  print(test);
}
```

Comment: The `.sort()` callback isn't quite right in that it never returns 0 for items that should be considered equal.

Answer (score 0):

I can sort easily using sort().

```
var List<String> hi = ['05stack', '03overflow', '01cool', '04is', '02uToo'];
  hi.sort();
  hi.forEach((element) {
    print(element);
  });
```

it prints:

```
01cool
02uToo
03overflow
04is
05stack
```

I am not getting any error of

```
type '_SecItem' is not a subtype of type 'Comparable<dynamic>'
```