# How to sort list that has custom element (not string or int)?

Tags: android, sorting, flutter, dart, comparable

I'm using the flutter_secure_storage package and I'm trying to sort the items in the list. The list is like: `List<_SecItems> hi = []`

and defined by:

```dart
class _SecItem {
  _SecItem(this.key, this.value);

  final String key;
  final String value;
}
```

The order of items in the list isn't kept. And using `hi.sort()` gives the message `type '_SecItem' is not a subtype of type 'Comparable<dynamic>'`

So how would I sort the strings in the list of _Secitem elements? The elements inside of List<_Secitems> are still strings.

Comment: You either can call [`List.sort`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.0/dart-core/List/sort.html) with a callback that indicates how two `_SecItem` objects should be compared, or you can make `_SecItem` implement the [`Comparable`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.6.0/dart-core/Comparable-class.html) interface and provide a [`compareTo`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.6.0/dart-core/Comparable-class.html) method.

Comment: I also don't understand why you [keep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61434038/is-there-a-way-to-sort-string-lists-by-numbers-inside-of-the-strings) [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61449971/how-do-i-sort-a-string-list-using-regular-expressions-in-dart) about this.  If the answers you've already received don't help, please explain why.

Answer (score 0):

you can sort object like this

```
hi.sort((a, b) => b.value.compareTo(a.value));
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement Comparable and write the logic in compareTo().

```
class _SecItem implements Comaparable<_SecItem> {
_SecItem(this.key, this.value);
final String key;
final String value;
   public int compareTo(Student st){  


   }
}
```