# Sort a map within a map and convert to list within a list

Tags: flutter, dart

Here's my data in Firebase:

```
prices
  price1
    priceAmount1: 10
    priceAmount2: 20
    priceAmount3: 30
  price2
    priceAmount1: 15
    priceAmount2: 5
    priceAmount3: 7
  price3
    priceAmount1: 2
    priceAmount2: 4
    priceAmount3: 6
```

If I straight away retrieve it. Sometimes the ordering is price2, price3, price1. So I tried sorting it like this:

```
      var sortedKeys = prices!.price!.keys.toList()..sort();
      for (var it = 0; it < sortedKeys.length; it++) {
        print('${sortedKeys[it]}');
      }
```

But since it becomes a list, I'm not able to access the map anymore. I wanted to sort the map within a map then store it in a list within a list. Please help. Thanks!

Edit:

```
final splayByPrice =
    SplayTreeMap<dynamic, dynamic>((a, b) => a.compareTo(b));

List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> priceAmountMap = [
        {
          'priceAmount1': 10,
          'priceAmount2': 20,
          'priceAmount3': 30,
        },
        {
          'priceAmount1': 15,
          'priceAmount2': 5,
          'priceAmount3': 7,
        },
        {
          'priceAmount1': 2,
          'priceAmount2': 4,
          'priceAmount3': 6,
        }
      ];

      Map<dynamic, Map<dynamic, dynamic>> priceMap = {
        'price2': priceAmountMap[1],
        'price1': priceAmountMap[0],
        'price3': priceAmountMap[2],
      };

      priceMap.forEach((key, value) {
        splayByPrice.addAll(value);
      });

      priceMap.forEach((key, value) {
        print('$key \t $value');
      });
```

What it prints, is still not sorted.

```
price2   {priceAmount1: 15, priceAmount2: 5, priceAmount3: 7}
price1   {priceAmount1: 10, priceAmount2: 20, priceAmount3: 30}
price3   {priceAmount1: 2, priceAmount2: 4, priceAmount3: 6}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart's default `Map` implementation is a [`LinkedHashMap`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/LinkedHashMap-class.html) that stores entries in order of insertion.

(You haven't provided code that clearly shows your data structure, so I'll use my own example.)

If you want the `Map` to be sorted by the keys' alphabetic order, then you could:

- Create a new `Map`, adding items to it in the desired order:

  ```dart
  var theMap = {
    4: 'four',
    7: 'seven',
    6: 'six',
    9: 'nine',
    5: 'five',
    1: 'one',
    8: 'eight',
    0: 'zero',
    3: 'three',
    2: 'two',
  };

  void main() {
    var sortedKeys = theMap.keys.toList()..sort();
    var sortedMap = {
      for (var key in sortedKeys)
        key: theMap[key]!,
    };
    print(sortedMap);
  }
  ```

  Or, if you want to update the existing `Map`, you could clear the existing `Map` and replace it with the sorted entries. (My [`dartbag` package](https://pub.dev/packages/dartbag/) provides a [`sort`](https://pub.dev/documentation/dartbag/latest/collection/SortMap/sort.html) extension method on `LinkedHashMap` to do that.)
- Update the existing `Map`, removing and re-adding items in the desired order:

  ```dart
  void main() {
    var sortedKeys = theMap.keys.toList()..sort();
    for (var key in sortedKeys) {
      var value = theMap[key]!;
      theMap.remove(key);
      theMap[key] = value;
    }
    print(theMap);
  }
  ```
- Use a [`SplayTreeMap`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/SplayTreeMap-class.html), which keeps entries sorted by a comparison rule.

  ```dart
  import 'dart:collection'; 

  void main() {
    var splayTreeMap = SplayTreeMap.of(theMap);
    print(splayTreeMap);
  }
  ```

If you need to sort the data only once, I'd use one of the first two methods.  If you're frequently adding new entries, then I'd use a `SplayTreeMap` instead of a `Map`/`LinkedHashMap` so that entries are kept in a sorted order. (But note that lookups, insertions, and removals in a `SplayTreeMap` are O(log n) instead of O(1).)

Also, [if you're sorting strings that contain numbers, you probably don't want to use the normal string sort](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61434038/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I try to use the SplayTreeMap but it sort for me. Am I missing something? I modified my question.

Comment: @Mr.Tacio You made the child maps `SplayTreeMap`, but `priceMap` is the one you actually care about sorting.

Comment: I just want to confirm. `print(splayTreeMap);` This print will only print up to a number of characters? I noticed that somehow the print is getting truncated.

Comment: You're probably getting truncated output because Android imposes limits on the length of log messages.