# How do i arrange a list of map items in a particular order in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, listview

Please, I am fetching a map list from an API and have to display it in a particular order on the UI. how do I go about it? The Order I need to follow is attached to the screenshot

[The order i want to display the data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXWuz.png)

the data is returned in the format above. This is the code contining what i have tried

```
class SelectRegularSeatsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String vehicleType, fromCity, toCity, date,seatNo, amount, time;

  const SelectRegularSeatsScreen({super.key, required this.vehicleType, required this.fromCity, required this.toCity, required this.date, required this.seatNo, required this.amount, required this.time});

  @override
  State<SelectRegularSeatsScreen> createState() => _SelectRegularSeatsScreenState();
}

class _SelectRegularSeatsScreenState extends State<SelectRegularSeatsScreen> {
  bool agree = false, oneSelected = false, twoSelected = false, threeSelected = false;
  bool fourSelected = false, fiveSelected = false,sixSelected = false;
  bool sevenSelected = false, eightSelected = false, nineSelected = false;
  bool tenSelected = false,elevenSelected = false,twelveSelected = false;

  @override
  void initState() {

    super.initState();


  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: ExchangeColors.whiteColor,
      //
      // appBar: AppBar(
      //     backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      //     elevation: 0.0,
      //     toolbarHeight: 80,
      //     iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.black, size: 30)),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
        child: Container(
          //margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 40),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 40),
                height: 150,
                width: width,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        BackArrowWidget(
                          color: ExchangeColors.blackColor,
                          onTap: (){
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },

                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 15,),
                        const LabelTag(
                            label: "Select \nSeat(s)",
                            fontSize: 25,
                            color: ExchangeColors.blackColor,
                            weight: ValgeeFontWeights.medium),

                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          height: 140,
                          width: 90,
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: AssetImage("assets/seats/upper_seat_1.png"), fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 3),
                              child: LabelTag(
                                label: parsedTime(widget.date),
                                fontSize: 14,
                                color: ExchangeColors.whiteColor,
                                weight: ValgeeFontWeights.light,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          height: 140,
                          width: 160,
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: AssetImage("assets/seats/upper_seat_2.png"), fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, top: 8),
                                child: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Column(
                                      children: [
                                        const Icon(Icons.circle_outlined, color: ExchangeColors.greenColor,size: 15,),
                                        const SizedBox(height: 2,),
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 2.0),
                                          child: CustomPaint(
                                              size: const Size(4, 40),
                                              painter: DashedLineVerticalPainter()
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        const Icon(Icons.circle_outlined, color: ExchangeColors.primaryColor,size: 15,),

                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                                      child: Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                        children: [
                                          LabelTag(
                                            label: widget.fromCity,
                                            fontSize: 15,
                                            color: ExchangeColors.blackColor,
                                            weight: ValgeeFontWeights.bold,
                                          ),
                                          const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                                          const LabelTag(
                                            label: "5hrs (Est.)",
                                            fontSize: 10,
                                            color: ExchangeColors.lineColor3,
                                            weight: ValgeeFontWeights.bold,
                                          ),
                                          const SizedBox(height: 10,),

                                          LabelTag(
                                            label: widget.toCity,
                                            fontSize: 15,
                                            color: ExchangeColors.blackColor,
                                            weight: ValgeeFontWeights.bold,
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),

                              Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 15, top: 15),
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: [
                                    ColumTitleTextCard(title: "Boarding Time:", text: widget.time),
                                    ColumTitleTextCard(title: "Trip Category", text: widget.vehicleType),

                                  ],
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),

              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                 Column(
                   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                   children: [
                     Container(
                         //margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 20,),

                         child: Image.asset('assets/backgrounds/regular_car.png', height: height*0.4,width: width*0.4,)),

                     Container(
                       margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 20,),
                       child: Column(
                         crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                         children: [
                           Text("Seats",
                               style:GoogleFonts.openSans(fontSize: 10,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: ExchangeColors.greyColor)),
                           const SizedBox(height: 5,),
                           Text(widget.seatNo,
                               style:GoogleFonts.openSans(fontSize: 36,fontWeight: ValgeeFontWeights.semiBold,color: ExchangeColors.greenColor)),

                           Text("Price",
                               style:GoogleFonts.openSans(fontSize: 10,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: ExchangeColors.greyColor)),
                           const SizedBox(height: 5,),
                           Row(
                             children: [
                               const NairaTag(fontSize: 24, color: ExchangeColors.blackColor),
                               Text(widget.amount,
                                   style:GoogleFonts.openSans(fontSize: 24,fontWeight: ValgeeFontWeights.semiBold,color: ExchangeColors.blackColor)),

                             ],
                           )
                         ],
                       ),
                     ),
                   ],
                 ),
                  Column(
                   children: [
                     Container(
                       height: height*0.5,
                       width: width*0.5,
                       margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 20),
                       decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                           image: DecorationImage(
                               image: AssetImage("assets/backgrounds/car_seats_background.png"), fit: BoxFit.contain)),
                       child: Column(
                         children: [
                           Padding(
                             padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20, top: 10),
                             child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/seats/car_header.svg', height: height*0.1,width: width,),
                           ),
                           Padding(
                             padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20, top: 20),

                             child: Row(
                               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                               children: [
                                 SvgPicture.asset('assets/seats/car_steering.svg', height: 40,width: 40),
                                 SeatSelector(
                                   seatNo: "01",
                                   status: oneSelected?"Selected":"Available",
                                   onTap: (){

                                   },
                                 ),
                                 //SvgPicture.asset('assets/seats/car_seat_1.svg', height: 40,width: 40,),
                               ],
                             ),
                           ),
                           Padding(
                             padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20, top: 17),

                             child: Row(
                               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                               children: [
                                 SeatSelector(
                                   seatNo: "02",
                                   status: oneSelected?"Selected":"Available",
                                   onTap: (){

                                   },
                                 ),
                                 SizedBox(width: 17,),
                                 SeatSelector(
                                   seatNo: "03",
                                   status: oneSelected?"Selected":"Available",
                                   onTap: (){

                                   },
                                 ),
                               ],
                             ),
                           ),
                           Padding(
                             padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20, top: 17),

                             child: Row(
                               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                               children: [
                                 SeatSelector(
                                   seatNo: "04",
                                   status: oneSelected?"Selected":"Available",
                                   onTap: (){

                                   },
                                 ),
                                 SeatSelector(
                                   seatNo: "05",
                                   status: oneSelected?"Selected":"Available",
                                   onTap: (){

                                   },
                                 ),
                                 SeatSelector(
                                   seatNo: "06",
                                   status: oneSelected?"Selected":"Available",
                                   onTap: (){

                                   },
                                 ),
                               ],
                             ),
                           ),
                           Padding(
                             padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20, top: 17),

                             child: Row(
                               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                               children: [
                                 SeatSelector(
                                   seatNo: "07",
                                   status: oneSelected?"Selected":"Available",
                                   onTap: (){

                                   },
                                 ),
                                 SeatSelector(
                                   seatNo: "08",
                                   status: oneSelected?"Selected":"Available",
                                   onTap: (){

                                   },
                                 ),
                                 SeatSelector(
                                   seatNo: "09",
                                   status: oneSelected?"Selected":"Available",
                                   onTap: (){

                                   },
                                 ),
                               ],
                             ),
                           ),
                           Padding(
                             padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20, top: 17),

                             child: Row(
                               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                               children: [
                                 SeatSelector(
                                   seatNo: "10",
                                   status: oneSelected?"Selected":"Available",
                                   onTap: (){

                                   },
                                 ),
                                 SeatSelector(
                                   seatNo: "11",
                                   status: oneSelected?"Selected":"Available",
                                   onTap: (){

                                   },
                                 ),
                                 SeatSelector(
                                   seatNo: "12",
                                   status: oneSelected?"Selected":"Available",
                                   onTap: (){

                                   },
                                 ),
                               ],
                             ),
                           ),
                         ],
                       ),
                     ),

                     const Padding(
                       padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
                       child: Row(
                         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                         children: [
                           IconTextContainer(text: "Booked", color: ExchangeColors.primaryColor),
                           SizedBox(width: 4,),
                           IconTextContainer(text: "Available", color: ExchangeColors.greyColor),
                           SizedBox(width: 4,),
                           IconTextContainer(text: "Selected", color: ExchangeColors.greenColor),

                         ],
                       ),
                     )
                   ],
                 )
               ],
              ),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20,),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: Material(
                        child: Checkbox(
                          checkColor: ExchangeColors.whiteColor,
                          //activeColor:ExchangeColors.blueColor ,
                          fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.grey),
                          //overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.grey),

                          value: agree,
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              agree = value ?? false;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 8,
                      child: Text("I have read and agree to the terms and conditions of service",
                        overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                        softWrap: true,
                          style:GoogleFonts.openSans(fontSize: 10,fontWeight: ValgeeFontWeights.semiBold,color: ExchangeColors.blackColor)

                      ),
                    )
                    //const LabelTag(label: "I have read and agree to the terms and conditions of service", fontSize: 10, color: ExchangeColors.blackColor, weight: ValgeeFontWeights.semiBold),
                  ],
                ),
              ),

              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20,right: 20),
                child: HomeTripButtons(
                  title: "Continue",
                  icon: Icons.arrow_forward,
                  backgroundColor: ExchangeColors.primaryColor,
                  onClick: (){
                    Get.to(() => PassengerDetailsScreen(
                        vehicleType: widget.vehicleType,
                        fromCity: widget.fromCity,
                        toCity: widget.toCity,
                        date: widget.date,
                        seatNo: widget.seatNo,
                        amount: widget.amount,
                        time: widget.time));
                  },
                ),
              ),

            ],
          )
        ),
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

I don't know if its best to use a listview.builder and how do i handle the index and arrangement of data to fit what i want in the UI/UX

Comment: Map's order depends on the kind of map.  See the first few paragraphs of https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Map-class.html for details.

Comment: There's a lot of code here, but none of it seems to reference `Map` or JSON.  If you actually want to sort a `Map`, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71107769/