# Flutter/Dart program to sort number in a list in descending order

Tags: flutter, dart

I am designing flutter app application that find the position of pupils through their total scores, I have used sort method but is not giving me a valid result.
'''List totals = [90, 50, 10, 5, 30, 9, 45];''' my result if I use I sort method *10, 30, 45, 50, 5, 90, 9*.
this is what I want to be my result */ 5, 9, 10, 30, 45, 50, 90*
please help me out

Comment: I suspect you have a list of *strings* and not a list of numbers.  If you want them sorted in a numeric order, you should parse each of the strings to a number first and then sort the list of numbers.  Also see [Is there a way to sort string lists by numbers inside of the strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61434038/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your `List` is of type `String`, that's why the order is different than comparing `int`. To fix this you parse the `String` to an `int` by using the [parse](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/int/parse.html) method.

```
  List<String> totals = ["90", "50", "10", "5", "30", "9", "45"];
  totals.sort((a, b) => int.parse(a).compareTo(int.parse(b)));
  print(totals); // [5, 9, 10, 30, 45, 50, 90]
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I have list in this format '''List<String> total = ['1@60', '2@40', '4@90', 8@20'];'''    Please how can I convert this kind of list to integer

Comment: Please open a new question for that

Answer (score 0):

try `totals.sort((a, b) => a.compareTo(b));`