# flutter dart sorting method does not work

Tags: android, ios, flutter, sorting, dart

```
var dataJson = response.body;
        dataJson = dataJson.replaceAll('[', '');
        dataJson = dataJson.replaceAll(']', '');
        dataJson = dataJson.replaceAll('"', '');
        var matchData = dataJson.split(',').toList();
        //matchData.sort((a, b) => a.compareTo(b)); I tested this too
        matchData.sort();
```

dataJson = `[KR_1, KR_3, KR_4, KR_2, KR_7, KR_6, KR_5]`

**I want to sort the list like this :**

`[KR_1, KR_2, KR_3, KR_4, KR_5, KR_6, KR_7]`.

Comment: i think the sort need 2 dots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that given a `String` `'["KR_1", "KR_3", "KR_4", "KR_2", "KR_7", "KR_6", "KR_5"]'` (which, given your code, is what I presume is what you really have), after removing the brackets and quotes, when you do `dataJson.split(',')`, the elements of the resulting `List` will still include the spaces.  The spaces at the beginning of some of the elements are what cause you to get an unexpected sort order.

(As an aside, [`String.split`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/String/split.html) already returns a `List<String>`, so calling `.toList()` on it again is unnecessary and wasteful.)

You could remove the spaces by using `dataJson.split(', ')` instead or by explicitly calling [`String.trim`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/String/trim.html) on each element.  But really you should not parse JSON yourself:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  var dataJson = '["KR_1", "KR_3", "KR_4", "KR_2", "KR_7", "KR_6", "KR_5"]';
  var matchData = json.decode(dataJson);
  matchData..sort();
  print(matchData); // Prints: [KR_1, KR_2, KR_3, KR_4, KR_5, KR_6, KR_7]
}
```

Be aware that the above sorts strings *lexicographically* (i.e, in character code order), so `"KR_10"` would be sorted before `"KR_2"`.  If you don't want that, then see: [Is there a way to sort string lists by numbers inside of the strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61434038/)

Answer (score -1):

try this;

```
final dataJson = ["KR_1", "KR_3", "KR_4", "KR_2", "KR_7", "KR_6", "KR_5"];
final data = dataJson.toList()..sort((a,b)=> a.compareTo(b));
log(data.toString()); // or use print
```

// result

```
[KR_1, KR_2, KR_3, KR_4, KR_5, KR_6, KR_7]
```

Comment: `list..sort((a, b) => a.compareTo(b))` is the same thing as just `list..sort()`.